# Is it possible to inject a background service to an apk?

Tags: android, apk, background-service

Is it possible to inject a background service into an already made APK without the source code?

Comment: No. I mean... No.

Comment: @TheLibrarian Even with reverse engineering?

Comment: I mean you can try to reverse engineer what it does. But you can't just add something of a parasite to an already compiled apk. Especially background service -there is a TON of stuff that you have to do to even be able to launch it as an owner of the apk - trying to hack it in. I will admit that I don't have the exact explanation for each of the steps but just no.